# Uncaught Exception[Object Object] using Graphql in Appsync with AWS Amplify in Ionic AWS Starter Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic3, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

When I started using the AWS Template of Ionic, The AWS Amplify Library does not include the Graphql Modules in the beginning, I Updated the AWS Amplify Library using "**npm install aws-amplify@latest**". After this when ever i am using API.Graphql function, it is showcasing the below error. 
I have already checked the documentation but it is showing nothing extra apart from this.
Please help me out on this. Stuck !!

[This is my function which is a Query i need to pass this query inside my Graphql function as stated in AWS Amplify Documentation. But it is returning Uncaught Exception[Object Object].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Ehc.png)

This is my function which showing the error

var GetEvent = `query GetEvent {
        getBinData(Bin_id:"AmbujaNeotia"){
          Area_id
          Bin_full_percentage
        }
      }`;
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(GetEvent));

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to parse what the [Object Object] is?  Maybe use a catch block on the API.graphql call?  That would be helpful in trying to chase this down.